# How to make a dock icon for a specific Terminal profile?

Tags: macos, terminal, dock, automation

I'm running **Big Sur 11.6.6**

I have a number of **Terminal** profiles. I know how to select any of these different profiles after I have started Terminal, but I'm wondering if there is any way to set up icons in the dock, each of which will open **Terminal** using a different one of its profiles.

I'm guessing that I possibly could somehow manage this via **Automator**, but I'm hoping that there might be a more straightforward way of accomplishing this, so that I can avoid Automator altogether.

Can I script startup as a document file so I can have shortcuts in my dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! I figured out the answer to my question.

All I have to do is start **Terminal**, go to **Preferences=>Profiles**, click on any given profile, and then click on the button at the bottom of the list of profiles which has a circle with three horizontal dots in it. In the drop-down that comes up, I can select **Export...** and the profile can then be saved as **[ProfileName].terminal**.

Then, I just need to go into **Finder** and drag that **[ProfileName].terminal** file onto the dock.

Comment: Mind if I change your command line font to bolds? We try to use code blocks for code and not just emphasis… awesome question. I’m sure this will help others.